# Find the value of 12x/y

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-curves

Given that $6x^2 - xy = 7y^2,$ find the value of $12x/y$.

I am totally stuck and can even find a way out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried dividing both sides by $y^2$?  (assuming that $y\neq 0$ that is).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. In the future, please format your math using MathJax. (It can be as easy as putting dollar signs around the equations, which I did for you. Click on the "edit" link to see.)

Answer (score 2):

If you divide the equation by $y^2$ you get a quadratic in $\frac xy$.  You should note that $x=0,y=0$ is one solution to your equation, but presumably you are being asked for another because $\frac xy$ doesn't make sense when $y=0$

Comment: If $x = 0$ then $y=0$

Comment: Do we need to explicitly state that when we divide by $x^2$ the value of $x$ should not be zero? I mean the final value of $12x/y$ is reachable only when $x$ is not zero. Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance:  yes, when you divide by a variable you should say something about why you are not dividing by zero.  Here the equation allows $y^2=0$, but the question shows that is not allowed.  Other times we would note that $y=0$ is a solution to the equation, then say we are now looking for other solutions.

Comment: The person asking the question should have stated that.  But yes if you are asked, point blank "what is the value of blah" and "blah" need not have a value you do have to point out "blah" might not have a value as that *is* part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=mx$, then $$7m^2+m-6=0 \Rightarrow m=-1, 6/7.$$
So $$12 x/y=-12~ or ~ 14.$$

Comment: Or $x=0; y=0$ and $12\frac xy$ is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You may also proceed as follows:

- $6x^2 - xy -7y^2= (6x-7y)(x+y) \stackrel{!}{=}0$

Not considering the case $x=y=0$ you get

- $6x-7y= 0 \Rightarrow \boxed{12\frac{x}{y} = 14}$ or
- $x+y = 0 \Rightarrow \boxed{12\frac{x}{y} = -12}$